# Will my job experience while completing degree count?

Tags: australia

I was about to graduate from my University in 2013 but due to doing a startup I couldn't. From September 2014 I started a job while I had still not completed my degree and still continuing that full time job. I completed my degree in April 2016 after giving the last exam. I am now trying to move to Australia. Will my experience gained before completing the degree count towards immigration? Thanks.

Comment: I can't find an official Australian site, but this [visa company](https://www.acacia-au.com/skilled-migration-points-test.php) says, "Thinking about your work experience overseas, in the last 10 years, how long have you worked in your nominated occupation or closely related skilled occupation (note that if you have a "skilled date" in your skills assessment, work experience prior to this would not count for points)."

Comment: @mkennedy: What does skilled date mean here?

Comment: Graduation date or other notable date.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can get references in correct format they will count just fine.

They need to be (for ACS) in following format and originals notarised by Australian Embassy (17 GBP per page)... Check what skill experience need to be listed for your profession, then make a form for your employer...

[image]